# could use put methode in my web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, put

I am a beginner and I'll know how to use the put method so that the user can add data, I work with restful architecture, java, json and apache here is the code I tested, I hope to find an answer here and thank you

```
@PUT
//path 
@Path("/carte")
//json form
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@PermitAll
public List<Carte> setAllCarte(@FormParam ("nom") String nom , @FormParam("prenom") String prenom , @FormParam("date") Integer date ,
                                 @FormParam("compte") Integer compte);
 //implimante the list with a json data
public List<Carte> setAllCarte(String nom, String prenom, Integer date,
     Integer compte) {
Carte list = new Carte();
list.setNom(nom);
list.setPrenom(prenom);
list.setDate(date);
list.setCompte(compte);

return setAllCarte(nom, prenom, date, compte);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create, per example, a HTML page with a form that point to your rest service.
Something like this:

```
<form action="[yourservicepath]/carte" method="put">
  Nom <input type="text" name="nom" /><br />
  Prom <input type="text" name="prenom" /><br />
  Date <input type="text" name="date" /><br />
  Compte <input type="text" name="compte" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But be aware that all params annotated as `@FormParam` are `String` types then you must receive them as `String` an try to convert'em inside your method.